# RecyclerView onClickListener Doesn't Work

Tags: android, android-activity

I can't pass intent by clicking reckclerview onclickListener from adapter. When I clicked any item then application is stopped. Here is the Log Cat....

```
Process: com.example.ilias.materialdsgn, PID: 3685
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName() on a null object reference
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4449)
at com.example.ilias.materialdsgn.VivzAdapter$MyViewHolder.onClick(VivzAdapter.java:72)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)`
```

and my Adapter code is...

```
public class VivzAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VivzAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private LayoutInflater infater;
List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();
private Context context;


public VivzAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
    infater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= infater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent,false);
    MyViewHolder viewHolder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information current=data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.iconName);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
public void delete(int position){
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        icon= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
        icon.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SubActivity.class));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You never assign the member `context` in your constructor. That is, `this.context = context;`.

Comment: Your error indicates, that your Context is null. And that the error occurs in line 72 in VivzAdapter.

Comment: And handling onClick in adapter is bad practice. Send event to object which created the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

try editing this (paste `this.context = context;`):

```
public VivzAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
    this.context = context;
    infater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}
```